# Java 7 browser plugin options

Tags: java, plugins

Back in the days of Java 5.0, I was able to tweak JVM options for the browser plugin in the Java control panel. Now with Java 7.0, there is no browser plugin tab anymore in the Java control panel.

Is it still possible to add JVM options for the browser plugin with Java 7.0? I'm talking about options like `-Xmx256m` or `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, go to Java Control Panel->Java and click "View". You'll then see the Java Runtime Environment Settings dialog. For each JVM you can add parameters in the Runtime Parameters column.

BTW, if you want to do this for all users you can pass a param to your applet in your HTML, e.g.:

```
<applet ...etc
    <param name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx256m">
</applet>
```

Comment: The control panel setting works only when 'Next generation' plugin is enabled. But the nextgen plugin doesn't work for me, and the Java Runtime settings don't seem to apply to the 'standard' plugin.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7198214

Comment: SO.. no way then at the moment? Setting it in the HTML code isn't possible for me, as it's not my HTML.